# Bootbox Prompt call back function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootbox

I want the buttons to show-up when user enters the correct string in the prompt dialog. But currently, the call back function gets invoked properly, but for the buttons to be visible, I have to call "checkPassword" twice.

Template:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-if="showEdit">                              
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Add New"> 
</div> 

 <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' ng-click="checkPassword()">Edit</`button>
```

Script

```
$scope.checkPassword = function() {

         bootbox.prompt("This is the default prompt!", function(result){ 
            if(result == "password"){
                $scope.showEdit = true;
            }
            else{
                bootbox.alert("Wrong password");
            }
         });
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Angular, but when you call `bootbox.prompt` inside of `checkPassword`, checkPassword is going to complete before your user has responded to the modal. I've mentioned this in the docs and in multple questions here on Stack Overflow, but Bootstrap (and therefore Bootbox) modals don't block the document like native prompts, alerts, or confirms. How you make this work, I don't know. There _is_ an Angular version, http://eriktufvesson.github.io/ngbootbox/, but I don't contribute there, so I can't tell you if it works any better.

Comment: I absolutely appreciate your response.Unfortunately, I could not get it to work and so used native prompts instead !